# How do you jump to the first commit in git?

Tags: git, github

How can I jump to the first every commit in  a git repository? Also, is there a way to do it on Github through the website?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To go the first commit of the repo, do

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git log --reverse`
3. The first entry in the output is the first commit.
4. you can switch to that commit by `git checkout <SHA-1>`, where  is the SHA of the commit(first one)
   Also, when you do `git log` you can easily navigate to the last entry to see the first commit.

All this can also be done in single command like `` git checkout `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD | tail -n 1` `` which means to switch to the last commit having no parent from the current HEAD

Note: if you used `--depth` option, you might not be able to see the actual first commit, to avoid this ensure you clone the full repo (without `--depth` option)